# propegation of EM waves

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation

WHY DO EM-waves PROPAGATE ? this might sound absurd and stupid...
but i am unable to reason why a time-varying electric and magnetic field must not be localized.
WHY is there a spacial shift in the oscillations instead of being just varying vector fields confined to the same region ?

Comment: Why shouldn't a solution to a wave equation propagate like a wave?

Comment: The propagation of the 'change' that occurs with time in the field present throughout space, occurs at c. The 'change' in electric field in a certain region creates a magnetic field, and this 'change' propagates along.

Comment: I'm saying why is there a shift in the location of time varying field

Comment: A standing wave is a possible solution to the wave equation.   Those  happen.

Answer (score 2):

The electromagnetic force doesn't travel instantly. In Classical physics it would take t=c*d ( where time is the time needed, c is the speed of light and d is the distance) for a charged object to repel or attract the other. The electromagnetic force travels with the speed of light.

So any motion that a charged object does it will actually alter the value of the force it would exert on any other object. Because according to Coulomb's law F=((Q*q)/r^2)*k it depends on the ditance. Since the force travels at the speed of light and not instatly that means that a charged object doing Simple Harmonic Motion would produce a change in the field which would change that way.

In a single close point in space the field would change value but that won't be the case for a very far away point to which the force didn't have enough time to reach yet. A point far away knows that the force has a single value but once enough time passes it will update it's information.

Look at the similarities with a wave in a rope. The molequles of the rope don't propegate, they just move up and down. But what does propegate is the energy. Far away points on the rope do excactly what the previous ones did. This is what happens in the EM wave too. The oscilation of the E vector is localized. But as you get further and further away, the E vector does what in the previous point did.

Comment: EM waves need no medium to travel.then how and why is energy propagated

Comment: If you push a box it will gain kinetic energy. Similarly if you move a charged object closer to another charged object it will repel it or attract it. But the second object will not notice that the forced changed right away the change in force will travel with the speed of light. That's what an EM wave is, a constant change in force. In fact radio waves are produced by oscillating electrons.